# Union of two tables and comparing a third for duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables that are all joined by an emailaddress.

What I'm trying to do is a union on 2 of the tables and find duplicates that exist in one but not both.

```
Select *
From tbl3 t3
LEFT JOIN (
Select emailaddress From tbl1 t1
UNION
Select emailadress FROM tbl2 t2    
) as customer 
ON t3.emailadress = customer.emailaddress
```

Is there away for me to find out if there is a duplicate record in tbl1 or tbl2 but not in both?

Thanks

Edit : Sorry I didn't word that very well, I'm trying to take the email address from table 3 and compare it with the emailaddress in table 1 and table 2 to see if there is only one record in either of those tables but not in both.

Comment: Sample data and desires results would help.  What do you mean "duplicates that exist in one but not both"?  How is something "duplicated" if it is not, well, duplicated?

Comment: Sorry Gordon, I just edited that to be more specific.

Comment: So, again, give example data and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `tbl3` to the other 2 tables with left joins:

```
SELECT t3.emailadress email3, t1.emailadress email1, t2.emailadress email2
FROM tbl3 t3
LEFT JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t3.emailadress = t1.emailaddress
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t3.emailadress = t2.emailaddress
```

You can also add a `where` clause like:

```
WHERE t1.emailaddress is not null or t2.emailaddress is not null
```

to filter out rows of `tbl3` that don't exist in any of the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm trying to do is a union on 2 of the tables and find
>   duplicates that exist in one but not both.

Yep, try a group-by and having as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl3 t3
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT emailaddress FROM tbl1 GROUP BY emailaddress HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
UNION
SELECT emailadress FROM tbl2 GROUP BY emailaddress HAVING COUNT(*) > 1    
) AS [customer] 
ON t3.emailadress = customer.emailaddress
```

Just to breakout the selects that make up the union so you can see that they return the dups:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution on SQL Server 2019 can be found in db fiddle link :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d587a893f98f80341bfd9a5a81480eb

Query is below,

```
SELECT
  tbl3.emailaddress,
  cnt
FROM tbl3,
     (SELECT
       emailaddress,
       COUNT(1) AS "cnt"
     FROM (SELECT
       *
     FROM tbl1
     UNION
     SELECT
       *
     FROM tbl2) tab
     GROUP BY emailaddress
     HAVING COUNT(1) > 0) tab1
WHERE tbl3.emailaddress = tab1.emailaddress
AND cnt = 1
```

Assumption: An emailaddress doesnt occur more that one in any of the tables tbl1,tbl2 and tbl3.